# Virtual Printer Monitor vs Windows7 x64 1722 error

Tags: c++, printing, virtual, monitor

I want to write my own port monitor for virtual printer app. Now i try to call some functions from Winspools.h, but every func returns error code 1722. Manual starting Spooler and RPCLocator services is not helpful. Here is my code:

```
BOOL Result;

MONITOR_INFO_1 monBuff[256];
memset(&monBuff, 256, sizeof(monBuff));
DWORD capacity;
DWORD returned;

system("net start spooler");
system("net start RPCLocator");

Result = EnumMonitors(NULL, 2, (LPBYTE)monBuff, sizeof(MONITOR_INFO_1)*256,  &capacity, &returned);
if(!Result)
    cout<<"Error: "<<GetLastError()<<" occured.\n";

MONITOR_INFO_2 monInfo;
monInfo.pName = "RedLangMonitor";
monInfo.pEnvironment = "Windows x64";
monInfo.pDLLName = "RedLangMonSrv.dll";

Result = AddMonitor(NULL, 2, (LPBYTE)&monInfo);
if(!Result)
    cout<<"Error: "<<GetLastError()<<" occured.\n";

Result = AddPort(NULL, NULL, "RedLangMonitor");
if(!Result)
    cout<<"Error: "<<GetLastError()<<" occured.\n";
```

please suggest me some solution to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is some strangely, but problem disappeared after 2 reboots. I know, that was not mystics, but i have no time to search the reason of this strange behavior.

Comment: Now i found reason - my AVP blocks access to winspool. Now I added rule for AVP.